# Iterating over List of Lists

Tags: java, iterator, sublist

I'm trying to iterate over a list os lists but I'm getting CME all the time even using Iterator to remove and add elements while iterating over the lists.

I searched here in the community for similar questions but those I found didn't help me. Really hope you guys help me to figure out how to do what I need to do.

I have I `ListIterator<List<Event<T>>> itrListsEvent = partitionSubLists.listIterator();`
`partitionSubLists` is A `list of lists`. So I have **one bigger List** and inside it I have **four sublists.**

I need to iterate over the sublists, and while iterating I remove and add elements. After finishing to iterate over the first sublist, I need to go forward to iterate over the second sublist and so on and so forth.

This is what I've done so far:

```
  public List<List<Event<T>>> partitionedLists (List<Event<T>> list)
    {     
        int listSize = list.size();
        int partitionSize = listSize / 4;

        List<List<Event<T>>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += partitionSize) 
        {
            partitions.add(list.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, list.size())));
        }        
        return partitions;        
    }

List<List<Event<T>>> partitionSubLists     = partitionedLists(List<Event<T>>);
ListIterator<List<Event<T>>> itrListsEvent = partitionSubLists.listIterator();

while(itrListsEvent.hasNext())
{
       List<PrefixEvent<T>> listPE  = new ArrayList<Event<T>>();            
       listPE   = itrListsPrefixEvent.next(); 
       ListIterator<Event<T>> itrEvent = listPE.listIterator();

       while(itrEvent.hasNext())
       {
          //here I remove and add elements inside the sublist.
          //when finished, I need to go back to first while and go forward to the next sublists
          //and in this moment, i got ConcurrentModificationException

         itrEvent.remove()
            .
            . 
            .
        // some code here

         itrEvent.add(new Event<T>);
       }

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to remove and add, as opposed to just use [`ListIterator.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-)?

Comment: @Slaw I will add the `partitionedLists` method.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a [mre] demonstrating the CME?

Comment: It's kind difficult to add the CME error here, but, it seems that, the suggestion of @AndyTurner helped me. I mean, instead of remove and and, I just replaced using `ListIterator.set` and I got the result I needed here. I'll do more tests here, but it seems worked.

Comment: Ok, @AndyTurner really helped, but, when I add an element in the end, I use a comparator to sort the elements on the list. If I use the `set` method of `LisIterator`, the order of the list stays different. Why? well, the elements are sorted according to a `double value`, and all of them starts with 1.0. When start to iterate, those values will decrease and, on each sublist, they need to stay sorted in decreasing order.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. As far as I understand, you could achieve it like this:

```
List<PrefixEvent<T>>  listPE   = itrListsPrefixEvent.next();
// No iterator.

for (int i = 0; i < listPE.size(); ++i) {
  listPE.remove(i);

  // some code here

  listPE.add(i, new Event<>());
}
```

This avoids a ConcurrentModificationException because you don't structurally modify the list after creating an Iterator.

If you don't actually require the "one element removed" list in between the `itrEvent.remove()` and `itrEvent.add(new Event<T>())`, you can continue to use the `ListIterator`, and then set the value to a new value:

```
itrEvent.set(new Event<>());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The `set` method helped me, but I forgot to mention the those elements that I add in the end of the while, they are sorted in decreasing order of their `double values`. With the set, this (as far as I know), can't be done, cause it only replace the object returned by `next()`;

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults if you put something back in a different position, how do you expect to iterate the list? As in, if you put it before the current position, you'll miss it; if you put it after the current position, you'll process that element twice.

Comment: @AntyTurner, you know how can I "reset" the outside iterator  "itrListsEvent"?. I know hasNext() go forward and don't return the cursor to the first position of it. What can I do to continuous iterating over the outside while it still has elements to iterate ?

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults you can simply recreate the iterator. But, since you're taking an element out and putting another element in, at what point would you stop iterating?